# Using vector to hold class objects

Tags: c++, class, vector

SOLVED: Used a vector of pointers instead

I have a class named Nurse and I would like a vector of size numNurses of Nurse objects. With each object having unique data.
I first attempted to do this with the code

```
std::vector<Nurse> allNurses;
for (int i=0; i<numNurses; i++){ 
allNurses.push_back (Nurse(input,numShifts,numDays,inRow,nurMaxDay,nurMinDay,1));
}
```

but I found that changing the data of any nurse, referenced by some
index into allNurses (`allNurses[0]` for example) would affect every
other member of the vector.

I figured that maybe I just needed to call new somewhere since I was probably never creating new objects. Trying something like

```
allNurses[i]= new Nurse(input,numShifts,numDays,inRow,nurMaxDay,nurMinDay,1);
```

> Resulted in an error (that I don't think is too important):
>
> Optimize_Schedule.cpp: In constructor
>   'Optimize_Schedule::Optimize_Schedule(int)':
>
> Optimize_Schedule.cpp:38:17: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand
>   types are 'Nurse' and 'Nurse*')
>
> ```
>  allNurses[i]= new Nurse(input,numShifts,numDays,inRow,nurMaxDay,nurMinDay,1);
>              ^ In file included from Optimize_Schedule.cpp:5:0:
> ```
>
> Nurse.h:15:7: note: candidate: Nurse& Nurse::operator=(const Nurse&) 
>   class Nurse{
>
> ```
>                                                                         ^
> ```
>
> Nurse.h:15:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Nurse*'
>   to 'const Nurse&'

Comment: When your vector grows, it's going to copy your objects around. The old objects will be destroyed and the new copied objects will take their place. Also, consider looking into `emplace_back` instead of `push_back`. (actually, rereading, I'm not sure why every nurse gets modified, and I'm not sure we have enough code to know why. You're definitely creating objects though with the first syntax).

Comment: Your first code sample is the correct way to have a vector of nurses that do not affect each other. If you are still having trouble with it, post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing the unexpected behaviour

Comment: There is a lot of code so I might recreate the problem later but I think it might be too much work for this hour. The way I know that it's not working is that every nurse has a schedule stored as an array of ints initialized to all 0s. Then I call assign(0) which assigns to schedule[0]=1 for allNurses[0]. After which I call allNurses[1].printSchedule() only to find my assignment for allNurses[0] affecting allNurses[1]

Comment: @NickHZ As others said, your first method should not cause one update to affect the other elements in the array. So maybe the problem is how each Nurse object holds this schedule array of ints -- maybe they are all pointing to the same array. If you can't post all the code, check if only that part is changing for all the Nurse objects, while other parts of the object perhaps don't change.

Comment: We need to see the definition of `Nurse` to know what is wrong with it. Your use of `vector` is fine.

Comment: Thanks guys. I made a vector of pointers instead and it's working great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The allNurses declaration is for a vector or Nurse objects, ***by value***:

```
std::vector<Nurse> allNurses;
```

So you do NOT want to call "new" which returns a *pointer*.
The complaint about 'operator=' is because this line tries to assign a Nurse *pointer* to a Nurse *instance*.

```
allNurses[i]= new Nurse(...);
```

Concerning the original symptom:
There isn't enough information to understand why changing one Nurse object might affect others -- however there may be a different explanation. Since this is a vector of objects (not a vector of object pointers), the default copy constructor is likely being used as the vector gets expanded. If Nurse contains any members that cannot be copied element-by-element, you'd need your own copy constructor. (Move constructor in C++11.)

The alternative might be to use a vector of (smart) pointers. Then "operator=" would work.
(If going down this route, consider using a smart pointer so there's no need to explicitly clean up all the vector elements when the vector needs to be released.)

As an aside, if you have C++11 and are using a vector by value, consider using "emplace_back" instead of "push_back" to append a newly constructed Nurse object in-place, as follows:

```
allNurses.emplace_back(input,numShifts,numDays,inRow,nurMaxDay,nurMinDay,1);
```

Comment: In re-reading your question, you mention that changing a Nurse instance affects ***all*** other Nurse instances. I suspect this is for a member that has memory allocated for it outside this object instance. Like a member variable inside Nurse that is a pointer to other information. (An array?)  If so, then this would then be true even when the Nurse instances were not inside a vector.